# C# Populate GridView from database with update and delete function

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have been hunting for a way to populate a GridView from a sql local db with edit and delete functionality without creating duplicates.

So far I have got as far as creating a SQL query, storing the results as a datatable and pumping that in to the GridView. I cannot seem to figure out how to go about managing edit and delete functionality and hoping someone here can help.

Much appreciated.

Here's how I am populating the GridView:

```
//Load data in to parameters gridview
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PowerShellManager.Properties.Settings.PSManagerConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand comm3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Parameters WHERE ScriptId = (SELECT Scripts.ScriptId FROM Scripts WHERE Scripts.ScriptName = @ScriptName) AND ProfileId = (SELECT Profiles.ProfileId FROM Profiles WHERE Profiles.ProfileName = @currentlySelectedProfile)", con);
            comm3.Parameters.AddWithValue("ScriptName", listView_Scripts.SelectedItems[0].Text);
            comm3.Parameters.AddWithValue("currentlySelectedProfile", currentlySelectedProfile);
            DataTable t3 = new DataTable();
            t3.Load(comm3.ExecuteReader());
            //variablesDataGridView.DataSource = null;
            parametersDataGridView.DataSource = t3;
            //variablesBindingSource.Filter = new 
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: wpf or winforms? is it bound? how are you supplying data? Pls provide some code, what you tried, and why it did not work

Comment: Windows Forms, data is supplied from SQL local Db in to a DataTable then added as the GridView's datasource. I have added code which is working to get data, I just need help on how to add edit and delete functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a simple application just for you and edited whole answer! This will be a very long answer. You can save new Person to database or delete a Person from database, aswell as from `GridView`. Here is code with some picture examples:

**Person class:**

```
public class Person
{

    #region Members

    private int _ID = -1;
    private string _FirstName = string.Empty;
    private string _LastName = string.Empty;
    private DateTime? _BirthDate = null;
    private string _PhoneNumber = string.Empty;
    private string _Email = string.Empty;
    private bool _Changed = false;

    #endregion

    public Person()
    {
        _Changed = false;
    }

    #region Methods

    public void Save()
    {
        if (!_Changed)
            return;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\sqlexpress;database=People;integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Person_Save";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", _ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", _FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", _LastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", _BirthDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", _PhoneNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", _Email);

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        _ID = dr.GetInt32(0);
                        _Changed = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error message");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\sqlexpress;database=People;integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Person_Delete";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", _ID);

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error message");
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int ID
    {
        get { return _ID; }
        set
        {
            if (_ID != value)
            {
                _ID = value;
                _Changed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set
        {
            if (_FirstName != value)
            {
                _FirstName = value;
                _Changed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _LastName; }
        set
        {
            if (_LastName != value)
            {
                _LastName = value;
                _Changed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime? BirthDate
    {
        get { return _BirthDate; }
        set
        {
            if (_BirthDate != value)
            {
                _BirthDate = value;
                _Changed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return _PhoneNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (_PhoneNumber != value)
            {
                _PhoneNumber = value;
                _Changed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _Email; }
        set
        {
            if (_Email != value)
            {
                _Email = value;
                _Changed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Changed
    {
        get { return _Changed; }
        set { _Changed = value; }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

---

**PeopleForm class:**

```
public partial class PeopleForm : Form
{
    public PeopleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FillDataSource();
    }

    public void FillDataSource()
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\sqlexpress;database=People;integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "People_Read";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        list.Add(new Person()
                        {
                            ID = (int)dr["ID"]
                           ,FirstName = dr["FirstName"] as string
                           ,LastName = dr["LastName"] as string
                           ,BirthDate = dr["BirthDate"] as DateTime?
                           ,PhoneNumber = dr["PhoneNumber"] as string
                           ,Email = dr["Email"] as string
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error message");
            }
        }

        personBindingSource.DataSource = list;
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Person person in personBindingSource)
        {
            person.Save();
        }
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Person)grdPeople.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Delete();
        personBindingSource.RemoveAt(grdPeople.CurrentRow.Index);
    }
}
```

---

**Stored procedures:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Person_Save]
     @ID int
    ,@FirstName nvarchar(30)
    ,@LastName nvarchar(30)
    ,@BirthDate date
    ,@PhoneNumber nvarchar(30)
    ,@Email nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@ID = -1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO People
        VALUES (@FirstName,
                @LastName,
                @BirthDate,
                @PhoneNumber,
                @Email)

        SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  People
        SET     FirstName = @FirstName,
                LastName = @LastName,
                BirthDate = @BirthDate,
                PhoneNumber = @PhoneNumber,
                Email = @Email

        WHERE   ID = @ID
    END

    SELECT @ID;     
END
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Person_Delete]
    @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE
    FROM People
    WHERE ID = @ID
END
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[People_Read]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   ID
            ,FirstName
            ,LastName
            ,BirthDate
            ,PhoneNumber
            ,Email
    FROM People
    ORDER BY LastName, FirstName        
END
```

You will have to bind your Person class to your `DataGridView` as binding source like this:

[image: Binding step 1]
[image: Binding step 2]

In the end you get working application that looks like this:

[image: Complete application]

Notice that I've changed colors just a bit, nothing special. I've added a few people as an example. You'll have to handle error for the wrong input in your birth date column, but have some fun exploring. I think I gave you more than enough to start your application.

*Have fun!*

Comment: This is helpful but because I an new to C# I need a bit of help actually writing those functions. I have hunted the net for a working example but so far haven't found anything I can understand or put together.

Comment: @AndrewMorpeth I've made you a huge favor by doing this edit man.. (=

Comment: You are an absolute legend!! I have successfully followed your instructions and its working great. I will now try and merge your methods with my original project where I got stuck :) Thanks so much!!

Comment: @AndrewMorpeth I'm glad you like it, good luck with your project :)