# C# DataGrid custom BindingSource with ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, combobox

msmolcic92 gave me some really great assistance creating a class to form a BindingSource. I have successfully merged his example with my project and now wish to extend it a little.

Here is the code - [C# Populate GridView from database with update and delete function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776741/c-sharp-populate-gridview-from-database-with-update-and-delete-function/)

I have a variables table that I would like use to populate a ComboBox within the parameters DataGrid which is populated by the example above. The idea is that the user will map variables to the the list of parameters.

[image: The below image should assist]

I need to be able to populate the ComboBox with all variables, save the selected variable and be able to recall this information on program load.

If anyone can help out I would really appreciate it as I am pretty new to C#.

Comment: Try setting the DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember properties of the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.  Use the DataPropertyName property to bind it to the value in your grid's data source.

Comment: Could you provide an example please?

Comment: You have to show your code first, and where you are having problems.  Some research is required on your part.  This topic is fairly common to find plenty of examples on the internet.